# Naturally generating an `EXCEPTION_FLT_DENORMAL_OPERAND` exception

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

## Question

How can I **naturally** (without `RaiseException`) generate an `EXCEPTION_FLT_DENORMAL_OPERAND` exception on Windows (x64 preferably)?

## Context

We have a program that can catch crashing programs, replay the bug and analyze the cause of the bug. It's way more complicated than a simple debugger as it can replay the crash, taint the memory for argument propagation, do a bit of concolic execution and other complicated stuff.

For this we need to test the program with various crashes, that is generating [Windows exceptions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winnt/ns-winnt-exception_record#members).

I know that I can just call [RaiseException](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/errhandlingapi/nf-errhandlingapi-raiseexception) with the required `dwExceptionCode` but in our case this is very different from having the same exception "naturally" raised. In our case, generating a `EXCEPTION_FLT_DENORMAL_OPERAND` while manipulating floating numbers.

## `EXCEPTION_FLT_DENORMAL_OPERAND`

According to the documentation the exception is raised if:

> One of the operands in a floating-point operation is denormal. A denormal value is one that is too small to represent as a standard floating-point value.

Denormal (a.k.a Subnormal) values are explained [thoroughly on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subnormal_number); generating them is also easy with some "quirky" C (C++) code:

```cpp
    const unsigned ux = 0xf; // denormal as float.
    const unsigned uy = 0x7; // denormal as float.
    
    //auto x = (float)ux; // this obviouly doesn't work as you end up with 15.f.

    auto px = (float*)&ux;
    auto py = (float*)&uy;
    
    auto x = *px; // denormal
    auto y = *py; // denormal
```

Note that I can see under the debugger that both `x` and `y` are denormal.

The code is compiled for the x64 architecture using the `cl` compiler and this function:

```cpp
DWORD ExceptionFltDenormalOperand(LPVOID lpParam)
{
    UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(lpParam);

    _control87(_EM_INVALID, _EM_DENORMAL);

    const unsigned ux = 0xf; // denormal as float.
    const unsigned uy = 0x7; // denormal as float.

    auto px = (float*)&ux;
    auto py = (float*)&uy;

    auto x = *px;
    auto y = *py;
    //auto y = 1.f;

    float sum = 0.0f;
    for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
        sum += x / y;
    }

    return  static_cast<DWORD>(sum); // avoid optimizing away the above computation.
}
```

Relevant Compiler Flags:

- Enable Enhanced Instruction ([`/arch`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/arch-x64)): Not set.
- Floating Point Model ([`/fp`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/fp-specify-floating-point-behavior?view=msvc-160#precise)): Precise
- Enable Floating Point Exception ([`/fp:except`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/fp-specify-floating-point-behavior?view=msvc-160#except)): Not set.

Note that the disassembled code shows that `XMM` (SIMD) registers are used, and not the x87 FPU (`ST(x)` registers); below is the division `x / y`:

```
00007FF7B46F1AF5     | F3:0F1085 C4000000       | movss xmm0,dword ptr ss:[rbp+C4]
00007FF7B46F1AFD     | F3:0F5E85 E4000000       | divss xmm0,dword ptr ss:[rbp+E4]
```

## Controlling the Exception

The [`_control87`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/control87-controlfp-control87-2?view=msvc-160) function is meant to be used when controlling the behavior of the floating-point control word, especially for denormal operands.

> The difference between _control87 and _controlfp is in how they treat DENORMAL values. For x86, x64, ARM, and ARM64 platforms, _control87 can set and clear the DENORMAL OPERAND exception mask. _controlfp doesn't modify the DENORMAL OPERAND exception mask.

The function is used as follows:

```cpp
    _control87(_EM_INVALID, _EM_DENORMAL);
```

While debugging:

```
// Before: MxCsr = 0x1F80

00007FF7B46F1A6A    | FF15 E0190100    | call qword ptr ds:[<&_control87>]

// After: MxCsr = 0x1E80
```

According to the Intel Manual, concerning the `MxCsr` register:

> Bits 7 through 12 provide individual mask bits for the SIMD floating-point exceptions. An exception type is masked if the corresponding mask bit is set, and it is unmasked if the bit is clear. These mask bits are set upon a power-up or reset. This causes all SIMD floating-point exceptions to be initially masked.

[image: MxCsr register]

By default the value is 0x1F80 (all masks set to 1). The value 0x1E80 indicates the bit 8 is 0 (where bit 8 is DM or `Denormal Operation Mask`):

```
0x1E80 in binary.

 _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ 
|3|3|2|2|2|2|2|2|2|2|2|2|1|1|1|1|1|1|1|1|1|1|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|
|1|0|9|8|7|6|5|4|3|2|1|0|9|8|7|6|5|4|3|2|1|0|9|8|7|6|5|4|3|2|1|0|
|‾|‾|‾|‾|‾|‾|‾|‾|‾|‾|‾|‾|‾|‾|‾|‾|‾|‾|‾|‾|‾|‾|‾|‾|‾|‾|‾|‾|‾|‾|‾|‾|
|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|1|1|1|1|0|1|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|
 ‾ ‾ ‾ ‾ ‾ ‾ ‾ ‾ ‾ ‾ ‾ ‾ ‾ ‾ ‾ ‾ ‾ ‾ ‾ ‾ ‾ ‾ ‾ ‾ ‾ ‾ ‾ ‾ ‾ ‾ ‾ ‾
```

## Result

The resulting exception (of executing the aforementioned code) **always** results in an `EXCEPTION_FLT_INVALID_OPERATION` (and not the awaited `EXCEPTION_FLT_DENORMAL_OPERAND`).

[edit] At the exception site, the `MxCsr` register value is 0x1E82; this demonstrates that bit 1 (DE: Denormal Flag) is toggled.

## Other Tests

- Since the exception description specifically refers to `One of the operands in a floating-point operation is denormal.`, using only one denormal operand - rather than two as in the example - exhibits the same result.
- Enabling `/fp:except` doesn't change the result.
- Enabling `/fp:strict` doesn't change the result.

Comment: It sounds like you want [`/fp:strict`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/fp-specify-floating-point-behavior#strict) rather than `/fp:precise`.

Comment: @IInspectable Thanks for you comment. Changing to `/fp:strict` yield the same result (`EXCEPTION_FLT_INVALID_OPERATION`). Checking `MxCsr` at the exception site shows that bit 1 (`DE`: Denormal Flag) is toggled, but Windows keeps throwing "invalid operation" rather than "denormal operand"... I'm thinking about inspecting the interruption vector 19 to see what's going on :(

Comment: The arguments to `_control87` look odd. The new value is 0x10, but the mask is 0x80000. Maybe I'm misunderstanding the documentation, but that doesn't look right.

Comment: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/-set-se-translator-callback-receives-wrong-excepti/1376613

Comment: why only "naturally" ? what the different between this and RaiseException ? at the end not cpu generate value `STATUS_FLOAT_DENORMAL_OPERAND` but exception handler